# Does Javascript have GDI+ similar library?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, gdi+, gdi

I need a javascript library for manipulating/processing images. Not inside DOM, but similar like GDI+ where I can pick an image from file system and manipulate it programatically (get pixel color, change pixel color, add shapes and text , etc..).

I searched goolge but couldn't find such library. So far the best thing I could only find is a library called jimp, but it seems very basic and high level.

Does Javascript have such capability? reading an image and extracting information from it?

Comment: If you're in a browser, the Canvas API lets you read image data. If not, there are Node packages that reproduce it. If not Node, please state your environment. =)

Comment: Actually it would be a web application, but the image will be used from file system. I actually don't mind loading the image in the browser if it helps. Does canvas provide the ability to read pixel properties? If not, do you know if any node packages?

Comment: Yes, the Canvas API supports that. See [`getImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData).